# Creating a Note Editor with Apple Pencil functionality?

Tags: ios, ios13, pencilkit

Does anyone know how to make Apple Pencil work well in the context of a UITextView? For example, using the Apple Pencil with TextKit to create a 'drawing space' that expands as the user draws more within the UITextView. Just like in the Notes app.

I thought PencilKit (announced at wwdc) would handle this but it looks intended more for situations where only apple pencil interactions occur - correct me if I am wrong. I want to do exactly what is done in the Notes app. I don't think PKCanvasViews would work, as the user could create many of them in a single UITextView. PKCanvasView also inherits from UIScrollView, which suggests that it was not intended for this. I would like the user to still have access to the toolkit that docks to the sides of the screen though..

I have never worked with Apple Pencil before but I expected there to be some sort of sample project for this exact scenario, a note editor with pencil functionality. I haven't found one though.

Sorry for not providing any code, but I guess my question boils down to: What is the 'best' way (using Apple's latest APIs) to implement this functionality?